# Create enum class to assign Index

Tags: c#

I get a string from input ,I want to give it a index like the following:

For example:

```
string Name = "Jack"
```

There are 5 possibilities :

```
Jack   = 1, 
Alice  = 2,
Stiven = 3,
Alex   = 4,
Katrin = 5
```

when I get Name from input I want to go through this enum class and get the index of it

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<string, int>` instead.

Comment: do you have this enum declared? if so please post the code. Or what do you mean by " this enum class " ?

Comment: @MongZhu I have no idea how to create it

Comment: Enums are not meant to store data like this; there are better data structures for this case.

Comment: you don't know how to declare an enum? Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum)

Comment: @SebastianHofmann can you tell me how to write it with Dictionary?

Comment: @MongZhu I know,but for example its not possible to write Mong Zhu=1,does not accept the space between

Comment: Or an HashSet<T> to avoid duplicate in your Collection

Comment: But you can write `new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Mong Zhu", 1 }}`.

Comment: The title is create an enum and the accepted answer is with a dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a dictionary better, they are exactly meant to store a value corressponding to a given object.

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>() { 
  {"Jack", 1 }, {"Alice", 2 }, {"Steven", 3 }, {"Alex", 4 }, {"Katrin", 5 }};

string name = "Jack";

int value = dict[name]; // returns 1
```

Comment: or `if (dict.TryGetValue(name, out var value)) {/* name found its index is value */} else { /* not found */}`

Answer (score 1):

you can try `Enum.TryParse`, following way :-

```
string Name="Jack";
enum CustomEnum {
  Jack=1,
  Alice=2,
  Stiven=3,
  Alex=4,
  Katrin=5
}

CustomEnum TheName;
if (Enum.TryParse(Name, out TheName))
{
    switch (TheName) { 
      case Jack: /* code here*/ break;
      case Alice: /* code here*/ break;
      /* and so on */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
using System;

public class Test {
 enum Names {
  Jack = 1,
   Alice,
   Stiven,
   Alex,
   Katrin
 };
 public static void Main() {

  string Name = "Alex";
  Names eName;
  Enum.TryParse < Names > (Name, out eName);
  Console.WriteLine((int) eName);
 }
}
```

Demo here : https://ideone.com/ArhV67

Answer (score 1):

First declare an enum:

```
enum Names
{
    Jack = 1,
    Alice = 2,
    Stiven = 3,
    Alex = 4,
    Katrin = 5
}
```

and then use `Enum.TryParse` to get the enum that matches `"Jack"`, at the end cast `myNames` to int to get the desired index :

```
string Name = "Jack";
Names myNames;
Enum.TryParse(Name, out myNames);
int index = (int)myNames;
```

Comment: You don't need to declare `myNames` earlier, that's the advantage of `out`. You can simply do: `Enum.TryParse(Name, out Names myNames);`

Comment: @L.Guthardt I tried it your way but it doesn't work. I'am using Visual Studio 2015

Comment: `TryParse` does return a `bool` that represents if the parsing did work or not.

Comment: @bradbury9 I know that it returns a bool but i didn't assing it to a variable because i don't have to use it. I use TryParse to avoid exceptions

Comment: @SlavenHvar Have a look at the [MSDN about out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). It is possible to instantiate the parameter in the *method parameter section*.

Comment: @L.Guthardt your way works only with C# 7. I am using Visual studio 2015 where new features of C#7 don't work. I tried your examples and it won't compile

Comment: @SlavenHvar Ok, I somehow missed that you wrote you are using VS2015.

Comment: @L.Guthardt no problem. Thanks for the info anyway.